# Javascript store object in combobox

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a bunch of objects of the format like:

```
var Manchester ={ 
     name: "Manchester",
     latitude:53.3,
     longitude:-2.2
};
```

stored in an array called `airports`.  I then have combobox with an `id` of `combo` that is being populated from an array of objects, with the combobox displaying the object's name:

```
for(var i=0; i<airports.length; i++){
    var opt=airports[i];
    var el=document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent=opt.name;
    el.value=opt;
    document.getElementById("combo").append(el);
}
```

I then want to be able to read two of the other attributes of the object:

```
var e = document.getElementById("combo");
var lat= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value.latitude;
var lon= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value.longitude;
```

However, when I do `console.log`s of `lat` and `lon` they are showing as undefined.

Is the combobox storing the variable as its value?  If not, how do I do so, if so how do I extract other information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option's value is used to store string rather than objects.

An alternative is using data attributes.

```js
var airports = [{
  name: "Manchester",
  latitude: 53.3,
  longitude: -2.2
}];

for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
  var opt = airports[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt.name;
  el.value = i;
  el.dataset.lat = opt.latitude;
  el.dataset.lon = opt.longitude;
  document.getElementById("combo").append(el);
}

document.getElementById("combo").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var lat = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.lat;
  var lon = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.lon;
  console.log(lat, lon);
});
```

```html
<select id='combo'>
<option>-----</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` is a string and therefore can't hold an object. Why not use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead?

e.g.

```js
var airports = [{
  name: "Manchester",
  latitude: 53.3,
  longitude: -2.2
}];

for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
  var opt = airports[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt.name;

  Object.keys(opt).forEach(function(k) {
    el.dataset[k] = opt[k];
  });

  document.getElementById("combo").append(el);
}

var e = document.getElementById("combo");
var lat = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.latitude;
var lon = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.longitude;
console.log(lat);
console.log(lon);
```

```html
<select id="combo">
</select>
```